# Android ContentObserver never stopped

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, calllog

I implemented a ContentObserver and it worked fine. But now everytime the ContentObserver is notified for some changes in the CallLog.Calls content provider, it runs the onChange() method without stopping.

I'd like that my observer runs once for each item that has changed in the content provider. So, if 5 new items have been added to the CallLog.Calls content provider, the observer must be notified 5 times, and for each notify to the observer, a new call to the onChange() method must happen.

Here is my code.

```
public class RatedCalls extends ListActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "RATEDCALLSOBSERVER";
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private RatedCallsContentObserver callsObserver = null;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor cursor;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(RatedCalls.this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getApplicationContext()
            .getContentResolver()
            .registerContentObserver(
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, true,
                    new RatedCallsContentObserver(handler));
    Log.d("FILLLIST", "calling from onCreate()");
}

class RatedCallsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public RatedCallsContentObserver(Handler h) {
        super(h);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "RatedCallsContentObserver.onChange( " + selfChange
                + ")");
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        fillList();
    }
}

private void fillList() {

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC ");
    Log.d("FILLLIST", "Calling from filllist");

    db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    int numberColumnId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int durationId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int contactNameId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
    int dateId = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int numTypeId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE);

    Date dt = new Date();
    int hours = dt.getHours();
    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
    int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
    String currTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    ArrayList<String> callList = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String contactNumber = cursor.getString(numberColumnId);
    String contactName = cursor.getString(contactNameId);
    String duration = cursor.getString(durationId);
    String callDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(dateId);
    String numType = cursor.getString(numTypeId);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("contact_id", 1);
    values.put("contact_name", contactName);
    values.put("number_type", numType);
    values.put("contact_number", contactNumber);
    values.put("duration", duration);
    values.put("date", callDate);
    values.put("current_time", currTime);
    values.put("cont", 1);
    getBaseContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            new RatedCallsContentObserver(handler));
    db.insert(CallDataHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    callList.add("Contact Number: " + contactNumber + "\nContact Name: "
            + contactName + "\nDuration: " + duration + "\nDate: "
            + callDate);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem,
            callList));
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change DB content inside of the `fillList()`, so `RatedCallsContentObserver.onChange()` is called again and again...

Answer (score 1):

include a date check in this query..   android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE > last date

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC ");
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Where should I add the date check? Should I do like this?
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " > ?", new String[] { lastDate }, null, null, null);

Comment: I dont think it will work because it will only get the calls with a date higher than the last date. But if its the same day. And if I just made a call, and want to make another

Comment: Check the arguments in query(),you can put some condition on that.

Is this problem resolved?