# Android sqlite log reports and db.close()

Tags: java, android, sqlite

The log reports that the database or cursor was not closed. I basically have an activity with a custom surfaceview and uses a handler to report back to the activity. When I receive the msg I show an alertdialog and also update the database.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
        case 1:
            dh.open();
            dh.updateEvent("id", "name", "someone");
            dh.close();
            successAlert.show();
            break;
        case 2:
            failAlert.show();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Previously I did not have "dh.close()" and thats when the log reported database/cursor not closed. But ever since I added that in, it takes a really long time to complete. Once I get the message, the system seems to hang. Am I doing something wrong or does it usually take this long. I have also tried using a try block with a finally to close the db.

EDIT:

```
public class DatabaseHelper {

private Database dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Context context;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    //database = new Database(context);
}

public void open() {
    dbHelper = new Database(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public void updateEvent(int id, String name, int other) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("id", id);
    cv.put("name", name);
    cv.put("other", other);
    db.update("stateTable", cv, "id=" + id, null);
}

public boolean checkState(int id) {
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("stateTable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToPosition(id - 1);
    int i = cursor.getInt(2);
    android.util.Log.d("semajhan", ": " + i);
    if (i == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Extended SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "events.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "stateTable";
private static final String ID = "id";
private static final String NAME = "name";
private static final String OTHER = "other";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE stateTable (id INT, name TEXT, other INT)";
private static final String DATABASE_UPGRADE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table";

public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    // added initial values
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_UPGRADE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

```
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): ANR in com.semajhan.soodles  (com.semajhan.soodles/.Level1)
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): Load: 1.64 / 0.56 / 0.26
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): CPU usage from 35716ms to -1ms ago:
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   44% 862/com.semajhan.soodles: 37% user + 7.2% kernel / faults: 853 minor
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   29% 61/system_server: 27% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 142 minor
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0.2% 731/com.android.quicksearchbox: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 30 minor
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0.2% 707/com.android.launcher: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 30 minor
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0.2% 801/com.svox.pico: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 363 minor
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0% 117/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0% 41/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): 99% TOTAL: 86% user + 13% kernel + 0% irq
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): CPU usage from 1969ms to 2620ms later:
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   54% 61/system_server: 48% user + 6% kernel
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):     40% 69/SurfaceFlinger: 40% user + 0% kernel
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):     10% 92/InputDispatcher: 7.5% user + 3% kernel
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):     1.5% 62/HeapWorker: 1.5% user + 0% kernel
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   44% 862/com.semajhan.soodles: 32% user + 12% kernel / faults: 2 minor
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):     24% 874/Thread-13: 24% user + 0% kernel
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):     23% 862/studios.soodles: 4.6% user + 18% kernel
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):     1.5% 867/Compiler: 0% user + 1.5% kernel
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):   0.8% 731/com.android.quicksearchbox: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61):     0.8% 732/HeapWorker: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
01-11 13:57:41.239: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): 100% TOTAL: 76% user + 23% kernel
```

Comment: The handler code looks OK, however we don't see how your `dh` is coded, so it's hard to say what could cause the delay.

Comment: Will post more code in a sec.

Comment: Okay, where is Database coded in? Unless it's part of the adk and I don't see it anywhere...

Comment: Database is the SQLiteOpenHelper extended class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first call to `getReadableDatabase` or `getWritableDatabase` of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance takes a *really* long time to complete. You shouldn't create a new `Database` object (your `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance) each time that you need to query the database. Try using the same `Database` instance within `DatabaseHelper`.

When using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, you don't want to close the `SQLiteDatabase` object for an `SQLiteOpenHelper` because it is shared; i.e. `getWritableDatabase` always returns the same `SQLiteDatabase` object.

Notice that your `checkState` method leaks a cursor. To help prevent cursor leaks, I always use a `try`-`finally` after obtaining a cursor. For example:

```
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("stateTable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        cursor.moveToPosition(id - 1);
        int i = cursor.getInt(2);
        android.util.Log.d("semajhan", ": " + i);
        if (i == 1) {
                return true;
        } else {
                return false;
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Comment: I think I understand what you have tried to explain to me. In my DatabaseHelper class, I create a new instance of SQLiteOpenHelper each time which you are implying not to do. I cannot seem to figure out HOW exactly I would create an SQLiteOpenHelper instance ONCE within my DatabaseHelper class and use it from there.

Comment: @semajhan: Add a private member variable to your activity for an object of type `DatabaseHelper`. Inside the `onCreate` method override of the activity you call DatabaseHelper#open. Inside the `onDestroy` method override of the activity you call DatabaseHelper#close.

Comment: @semajhan: Actually, I see that it's your `Handler` that needs access to the `DatabaseHelper` instance. Are you programming a service? If so, add the private member variable for an object of type `DatabaseHelper` to the service. Inside the `onCreate` method override of the service you call DatabaseHelper#open. Inside the `onDestroy` method override of the service you call DatabaseHelper#close.

Comment: @semajhan: I should also say that in this case, creating only one `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance is accomplished by creating only one `DatabaseHelper` instance. My two comments above are how to use only one `DatabaseHelper` instance.

Comment: I've narrowed down my problem to: how to access a single db from multiple activities. Since I have over 50 activities needing to update the db, i've come up with two solutions and they are to pass a handler to another activity with intents and the other is services.

Comment: @semajhan: If you have 50 activities that need to access a single database, then I suggest writing a content provider.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if the underlying problem regarding the cursor not being closed is the same as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464892/android-error-close-was-never-explicitly-called-on-database/4465047#4465047): Activities need to have an `onDestroy` method that closes the DatabaseHelper. (All I can tell right now is that you don't **show** an `onDestroy` method, but this is clearly just a portion of your code.) I also blogged about this problem [here](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-closing-those-database-objects/).

You also wrote that "But ever since I added [`dh.close()`], it takes a really long time to complete."  Are you doing a lot of writes to the database? Maybe you need to use transactions to flush those writes periodically. If you're only reading from the database, then I have no idea why the `close` call would take a long time to complete. But without seeing more of your code, these are only guesses.

<s>EDIT: [ccheneson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660363/android-sqlite-log-reports-and-db-close/4661257#4661257)'s advice about calling `db.close()` before calling `dbHelper.getReadableDatabase()` is worth following. However, you need to check that db isn't null. This changes the `checkState` to:</s>

```
public boolean checkState(int id) {
    if (db != null) {
        db.close();
    }
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    // ... etc ....
```

If that turns out to be the real problem, please accept ccheneson's answer, not mine.

## (Above edit was incorrect; I should have known better! See below instead.)

**EDIT 1**: I'm not sure why you are re-opening the database at all in this method. Assuming that your `DatabaseHelper.open` method is invoked, you have a readable **and** writeable database handle. `checkState` doesn't need to re-open it to perform reads.

**EDIT 2**: However, [SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase()) will almost always return the same database handle that was returned from `SQLiteOpenHelper.getWriteableDatabase`. You **do not** need to close that database handle explicitly; the **SQLiteOpenHelper** will close it for you. You **do** need to be sure that `SQLiteOpenHelper.close` is invoked when your activity is destroyed (as I wrote above.)

Comment: I'm checking your blog and link right now. I'm only writing one row of 3 columns: an INT, TEXT, and another INT. Being pretty new to SQL but IMHO writing just 1 row of 3 cols should be very fast.

Comment: So basically when I create an instance of SQLiteOpenHelper I have already "opened" the database for read and write? And for reading I do not need to explicitly call db.getReadableDatabase()?

Comment: @semajhan: Not quite. The database isn't opened until you've called `db.getWriteableDatabase` or `db.getReadableDatabase`. But calling `db.getWriteableDatabase` allows you to read from **and** write to the database. Hence I don't think you need to call `db.getReadableDatabase` **after** you've already called `db.getWriteableDatabase`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So I would never need to call getReadableDatabase() if I have already called getWritableDatabase(). But say I AM calling getReadableDatabase() after getWritableDatabase(), does that mean I am opening the db twice and causing a leak maybe?

Comment: @semajhan: No, it does not cause a leak. `SQLiteOpenHelper` keeps a reference to the database handle that it's given you. If you re-open the database for reading or writing, it will simply return that handle (assuming no errors: you have appropriate permissions, the disk is not full, etc.) In fact, if you look at the source code, you can see that calling `getReadableDatabase` will often give you a database that's already writeable! (See http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java;hb=HEAD )

Answer (score 1):

```
public void close() {
    dbHelper.close(); // to change to db.close(); ?
}
```

I think here you would want to close the database handle `db` instead of the `dbHelper`

Also in you `checkState` method:

```
public boolean checkState(int id) {
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("stateTable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToPosition(id - 1);
    int i = cursor.getInt(2);
    android.util.Log.d("semajhan", ": " + i);
    if (i == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You would want to close the cursor like:

```
int i = cursor.getInt(2);
cursor.close();
android.util.Log.d("semajhan", ": " + i);
```

Comment: The thing is, I have already done all that. In my older code, I had the handle to db close instead of dbHelper. And in my checkState method I had also called cursor.close(). But that resulted in a leak. Once I switched from closing db to dbHelper, the leak went away but I got some freaky error in my log. Just a bunch of numbers and giving me a percentage: user=72% kernel=28% something like that.

Comment: Also, when you call `db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();`, try closing the db first: `db.close(); db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();`. After that, no other idea :)

Comment: Closing the db first results in a force close =[

Comment: Look at the LogCat under DDMS to see if there is any stack trace that can help us debug

Comment: Found DDMS but in the LogCat I don't see anything related to "stack trace".

Comment: You can go straight to LogCat by going to Window -> Show View -> Other -> Under Android, select LogCat and you will see the LogCat window appear. Run your project and you will see stack trace in case of errors

Comment: I don't see any "caused by" clauses only a Reason: KeyDispatchingTimedOut.

Comment: ccheneson's comment about `db.close()` is correct as far as it goes, but you probably want to change it to `if (db != null) {db.close();}` By the way, I think it's probably not a good idea to use the same `db` member variable for both the readable and writeable database handles. Why not get a single, writeable database handle at the start of your activity, and leave it at that?

Comment: I read somewhere here that it was good practice to open the DB ALAP and close it ASAP. I'm guessing this is not the case?

Comment: @ccheneson: `SQLiteOpenHelper` maintains a reference to the database handle that it's opened. Any database handle that's opened through `SQLiteOpenHelper` should be closed by calling `SQLiteOpenHelper.close()`.

Comment: For the record, my comment 3 comments above (mentioning `if (db != null) {db.close();}`) was incorrect. My answer, elsewhere on this page, is more correct.