# Close() was never explicitly called on database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have try this code on DatabaseHelper.java

**Line Number 34**

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.mycontext = context;
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if (dbexist) {
        // System.out.println("Database exists");
        opendatabase();
    } else {
        // System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        createdatabase();
    }
}
```

**Line number 64**

```
private boolean checkdatabase() {
    // SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
    boolean checkdb = false;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE) != null;
        checkdb = dbfile.exists();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    }

    return checkdb;
}
```

**Line number 44**

On create method menu.java

```
try {
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    } catch (IOException e2) {

        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        db.createdatabase();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     db.getReadableDatabase();

    db.opendatabase();
    Random rand = new Random();
    randomJokId = rand.nextInt(603 - 1) + 1;
    cur = db.jokOfTheDay(randomJokId);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    String fullJok = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
    String Jok = "";
    Jok = fullJok.substring(0, 55);
    jok_of_the_day.setText(Jok + "...  Read more");

    Log.d(TAG, "" + randomJokId);
}
```

**Getting this error message**

Another important things, I have this error message occurs **three time**.

```
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.horror.android/databases/jokesdatabase.sql' 
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at com.horror.android.DatabaseHelper.checkdatabase(DatabaseHelper.java:64)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at com.horror.android.DatabaseHelper.createdatabase(DatabaseHelper.java:45)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at com.horror.android.UltimateJokesMenu.onCreate(UltimateJokesMenu.java:51)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-19 13:49:41.284: ERROR/Database(10932):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: [Found answer here][1]:
"Make DBManager a singleton."


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424585/close-was-never-explicitly-called-on-database#comment-9002897

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `SQLiteDatabase.close()` at the end of your `try` in the `checkDatabase` method.

Comment: I have try this but it is not working. only Force close appear on my screen.

Answer (score 1):

When your data base use became over then better approach to use `SQLiteDatabase.close()`.Close 
cursor also `cursor.close();`

For cursor use startmanagincursor(cursor).just after assigning it some value

And remember sometimes if you donot close database then it can create severe problem

Answer (score 0):

use `db.close();` to close your Database and `cur.close();` to close your cursor after you end working with them.

Answer (score 0):

Close your database on the `onStop()` method and use `startmanagingcursor()` with all your cursors to handle its lifecycle automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Closing in `onPause` is just enough as it precedes `onStop` on the [activities lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). Using `startManagingCursor` besides being deprecated it may  carry you problems of handling cases of updating view. I see two issues to assess:

- Closing db. Is enough to follow the answer given here  [Android error - close() was never explicitly called on database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464892/android-error-close-was-never-explicitly-called-on-database), that is:

  > Literally understand database is not normally closed, the actual
  >   because repeated instantiation your database, or connect you have been
  >   set up, and you and try to open another connection there will be no
  >   exception. So the solution is, make sure that you open only a
  >   connection.

  In small words: each time you open a db connection close it. This can be implemented be assuring that there is only one connection, you can for example use the method [`isOpen`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#isOpen%28%29) or assure that each time you open it is closed.
- Closing cursors, as I said before using `startManagingCursor` is not good idea. Instead you should use the support library and using the CursorLoader approach, it involves using a ContentProvider but if you think is an overkill you may read about [CursorLoader usage without ContentProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182485/usage-cursorloader-without-contentprovider)