# how to avoid "close() was never explicitly called on database in SQLiteDatabase"

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android error - close() was never explicitly called on database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464892/android-error-close-was-never-explicitly-called-on-database)

I have a problem in my android app.

I have a singleton implemented which has a method with the following code:

```
public Cursor getFooCursor(Context context)
{
    StorageDBOpenHelper helper = new StorageDBOpenHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.query("Foo", new String[] {"_id", "Titel"}, null, null, null, null, "Test DESC");

    return c;
}
```

when i use this, i sometimes get the error: `SQLiteDatabase: close() was never explicitly called on database`

**how to avoid this?** the problem is, i can not simply make a `db.close()` befor i `return c`, because then its empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I use is to pass an instance of the `db` to a class that returns the `cursor`:

```
StorageDBOpenHelper helper = new StorageDBOpenHelper(context);
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

public Cursor getFooCursor(Context context, SQLiteDatabase db ) {
      Cursor c = db.query("Foo", new String[] {"_id", "Titel"}, null, null, null,
 null, "Test DESC");
      return c;
 }

db.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Clients should open the database, then use this method to fetch the cursor, then close both the cursor and the database when they are finished. I would recommend not using a singleton here. Instead do something like this:

```
public class FooDB
{
    private SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    private void open() throws SQLiteException
    {
        if (db != null)
        {
            throw new SQLiteException("Database already opened");
        }

        // Create our open helper
        StorageDBOpenHelper helper = new StorageDBOpenHelper(context);
        try
        {
            // Try to actually get the database objects
            db = m_openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (db == null)
        {
            throw new SQLiteException("Failed to open database");
        }
    }

    private void close() throws SQLiteException
    {
        if (db != null)
        {
            db.close();
            db = null;
        }        
    }

    public Cursor getFooCursor(Context context)
    {
        if(db == null)
            throw new SQLiteException("Database not open");    

        Cursor c = db.query("Foo", new String[] {"_id", "Titel"}, null, null, null, null, "Test DESC");

        return c;
    }
}
```