# SQLiteOpenHelper and close method

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm making some tests and every time I call to [SQLiteOpenHelper.close()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#close%28%29) and then I try to reopen the database with, for example, [SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29) I get the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase`

Is there some way of reopen the database? or I should re-create the SQLiteOpenHelper object?

Here goes the code, it crashes the second time the method getNoteCount is called

```
public DBController(Context ctx) {
    this.mContext = ctx.getApplicationContext();
    mDbHelper = new OpenHelper(mContext);
}

public int getNoteCount(){
     SQLiteDatabase mDb =mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
     Cursor c= mDb.query("notes", null, null, null, null, null, null);
     int result=c.getCount();
     c.close();
     mDb.close();
     return result;
}



private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    }
    ............
}
```

I'm considering to make something like this:

```
public abstract class DBHelper {

    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private int openCount = 0;

    protected abstract SQLiteOpenHelper newSQLiteOpenHelper();

    public void openDatabase() {
        open();
    }

    public void closeDatabase() {
        close();
    }

    protected synchronized SQLiteDatabase open() {
        if (openHelper == null) {
            openHelper = newSQLiteOpenHelper();
        }
        openCount++;
        return openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    protected synchronized void close() {
        openCount--;
        if (openCount == 0) {
            openHelper.close();
            openHelper = null;
        }

    }

}
```

and use it this way

```
public class DBController extends DBHelper{
    public  DBController(Context ctx) {
        this.mContext = ctx.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected SQLiteOpenHelper newSQLiteOpenHelper() {
        return new OpenHelper(mContext);
    }

    public int getNoteCount(){
         SQLiteDatabase mDb =open();
         Cursor c= mDb.query("notes", null, null, null, null, null, null);
         int result=c.getCount();
         c.close();
         close();
         return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just don't close the db.

Comment: Thats what I was doing till before start testing this new methods, but I didn't know if leaving the db open could result in memory leaks or something similar. Then can I leave it opened?

Comment: Please consider using database instance in a singleton pattern. SQLite database is supposed to be used that way and not be closed. Here's an example db.tt/z7bvFkVJ take a look into HistoryDBSQLiteHelper.getInstance()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read, your not supposed to close the database until the application is destroyed.  See [Android error - close() was never explicitly called on database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464892/android-error-close-was-never-explicitly-called-on-database)