# In my android application always show the database leak even i close the cursor

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

Here is my log message

```
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.param.calltracker/databases/calls' 
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:544)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at com.param.calltracker.DatabaseHelper.getUnsendData(DatabaseHelper.java:94)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at com.param.calltracker.InternetChecker.onReceive(InternetChecker.java:52)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    09-17 14:27:45.203: E/Database(12311):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.param.calltracker/databases/calls' 
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:544)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at com.param.calltracker.DatabaseHelper.getUnsendData(DatabaseHelper.java:94)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at com.param.calltracker.InternetChecker.onReceive(InternetChecker.java:52)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    09-17 14:27:45.283: E/Database(12311):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.param.calltracker/databases/calls' 
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:544)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at com.param.calltracker.DatabaseHelper.getUnsendData(DatabaseHelper.java:94)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at com.param.calltracker.InternetChecker.onReceive(InternetChecker.java:52)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    09-17 14:27:45.673: E/Database(12311):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.param.calltracker/databases/calls' 
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:544)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at com.param.calltracker.DatabaseHelper.getUnsendData(DatabaseHelper.java:94)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at com.param.calltracker.InternetChecker.onReceive(InternetChecker.java:52)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12

311):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-17 14:27:46.033: E/Database(12311):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i have closed `cursor` properly but still show the error  `close() was never explicitly called on database`

help me..

Comment: This should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464892/android-error-close-was-never-explicitly-called-on-database

Comment: Close your cursor and helper in onDestroy also

Comment: if close the database it will crash the app,because it always running in background.

Comment: database and cursor are 2 different things. it is possible android is complaining about not closing the database.

Comment: then how to close the db without crash my app

Comment: @chimbu `db = databaseInitializer.getWritableDatabase(); db.close();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this code where your process is end or where you want to close the database.

```
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
    db.close();

    or

   dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also close the database in the `onDestroy()` method with the same instance you opened the database:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Close the database here
}
```