# issues in sqlitedatabase and data display as cardview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

When i am clicking on display contacts button first contact display and next contacts are cannot display it shows exception how can i solve this exception any one can solve this error with u r briliance it shows error in opeNDatabase method?

```
public class ShowContacts extends Activity
{
private SQLiteDatabase db;
DbOperations doo;
private List<Contacts> contactsList;
private RecyclerView rv;
private Cursor c;
String names,email,address;
int phone;
String read_query = "select * from "+ ContactsTask.ContactsEntry.TABLE_NAME;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recycle_layout);
    doo = new DbOperations(this);
    openDatabase();
    rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    initializeData();
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    ContactAdapter cc = new ContactAdapter(contactsList);
    rv.setAdapter(cc);
}
public  void initializeData() {
    try {
        contactsList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            db = doo.getReadableDatabase();
            c = db.rawQuery(read_query, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            while (!c.isLast()) {
                names = c.getString(0);
                phone = c.getInt(1);
                email = c.getString(2);
                address = c.getString(3);
                contactsList.add(new Contacts(names, phone, email, address));
            }
            c.isLast();
            names = c.getString(0);
            phone = c.getInt(1);
            email = c.getString(2);
            address = c.getString(3);
            contactsList.add(new Contacts(names, phone, email, address));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //exception handling
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                c.close();
            }
        }
    /*BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute("get_info");*/
    }catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}

private void openDatabase() {
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("contactDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
}
```

}

logcat error

```
06-28 23:22:34.885 20407-20418/com.example.anilkumar.contactstask    E/SQLiteDatabase: close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.example.anilkumar.contactstask/databases/contactDB' 
                                                                                android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1943)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1007)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:962)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1043)
                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1036)
                                                                                    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:761)
                                                                                    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:215)
                                                                                    at com.example.anilkumar.contactstask.ShowContacts.openDatabase(ShowContacts.java:77)
                                                                                    at com.example.anilkumar.contactstask.ShowContacts.onCreate(ShowContacts.java:32)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: actually i am creating data will saved and first data only shows next data cannot be show it shows exception.it shows error on openDatabse method

Comment: hello reply please

Comment: Literally copied the error you got, pasted in google. ended up with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464892/android-error-close-was-never-explicitly-called-on-database). DUDE GOOGLE FIRST, ASK LATER.

Comment: no use when i m serch in google also

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
db.close();
```

after

```
db = doo.getReadableDatabase();
c = db.rawQuery(read_query, null);
```